# Is there a WordPress form plugin that can easily be configured for Google Analytics goals?

Tags: forms, google-analytics

I don't want to have to make use of a destination url, so ideally I would like to be able to add the onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/G1/whatever']);" event to the submit button on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.bobzien.com/2010/10/22/google-analytics-goals-with-contact-form-7-the-right-way/) seems to be a valid answer:

Use [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/). In the "Additional Settings" box enter the following: 
`on_sent_ok:"_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/G1/whatever']);"`

Where `/G1/whatever` is the Goal URL you set on your Google Analytics options page.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) and then attaching a jQuery click event to the submit button:

```
$(".wpcf7-submit").click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/G1/whatever']);
});
```